# Parse.com push api - randomly returns 404

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with parse api. I'm sending this data:

```
{
    "where": {
        "deviceType": "android"
    },
    "data": {
        "action": "somestring",
        "aps": {
            "alert": "some title",
            "id": 4353453,
            "s": "some_short_string"
        }
    }
}
```

to `https://api.parse.com/1/push` using `POST` method with headers:

```
Content-Type: "application/json",
X-Parse-Application-Id: "myid",
X-Parse-REST-API-Key: "mykey",
User-Agent: "PHPWebapiClient"
```

Api returns mostly status 200, but sometimes it returns 404. Of course in this case notifications wont work, and even don't appear in parse admin. It seems totally random, i can't  determine the cause. Interestingly api always return this header:

```
http_code: "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established"
```

no matter what response code is returned.

I tried resending request, but this didn't help.

Is there anyone experiencing similar problems? Please help me sort this out.

Comment: Could it be that you're reaching the burst limit of 30 requests/second?

Comment: No, this is definitely not the case.